# Statistics: Joint Moment Generating Function Question

Tags: statistics

I've got another moment generating function question. I've uploaded the question as a link.

*Joint Moment Generating Question:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ0zb.png

My Solution: Not exactly sure how to approach this one

Also just another clarification. If the  correlation between random variables X and Y is zero, are X and Y are independent? I do know that if Covariance(X,Y) = 0, X and Y are said to be uncorrelated. But how about for correlation?

Thank you so much for your help guys!! Much appreciated =)

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have zero covariance they will have zero correlation, but might not be independent.  For instance, if $X\sim N(0,1)$ then $X$ and $X^2$ are uncorrelated, but not independent.

Comment: Suppose $X = 1,\,0,\text{ or }-1$ each with probability $1/3$ and $Y=X^2.$ Then $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=0$ but clearly $X$ and $Y$ are not at all independent. Thus uncorrelatedness does not entail independence. Independence, however, does entail uncorrelatedness provided the variances of the random variables are finite. $\qquad$

Comment: I just noticed that it says PAIRWISE independent. Thus it doesn't fully say what the joint distribution is, and hence we can't be sure what the m.g.f. is. But we _can_ rule out all but one of the multiple-choice answers; that one is the only one that _could_ be the m.g.f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
M_{bX_1,\ldots,bX_n} (t_1,\ldots,t_n) & = \operatorname{E}(e^{t_1(bX_1)\,+\,\cdots 
\,+\,t_n (bX_n)}) \\
& = \operatorname{E}(e^{(bt_1)X_1 \,+\,\cdots\,+\,(bt_n)X_n}) = M_{X_1,\ldots,X_n} (bt_1,\ldots,bt_n)
\end{align}

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Can someone please expand on this?

Comment: @user473207 : Only one of the four multiple-choice answers has $bt_1,\ldots,bt_n$ where $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ would otherwise have appeared.

Comment: The question asks for the joint moment-generating function of $bX_1,\ldots,bX_n.$ The answer shows that it must be a function of $bt_1,\ldots,bt_n.$  Only one of the four multiple-choice answers is a function of $bt_1,\ldots,bt_n.$ If there's something you don't understand in that, can you be specific about what it is?

Comment: I need to show the answer in the form that is given in the options. I'm not exactly sure how to do that

Comment: @user473207 : If you can show that $ \displaystyle M_{X_1,\ldots,X_n}(t_1,\ldots,t_n) =  \prod_{i=1}^n (1-t_i)^{-\alpha} $ then what I wrote in the answer finishes the problem.